# Extract values from Boolean Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, boolean-logic

I want to extract values/variables from boolean query
For e.g

The boolean query is:

("Asset Data Management") AND "Data Scientist" AND ("Data Science & Analysis" OR "Financial Modelling" OR "Credit Structuring") AND ("Goldman Sachs" OR "Deutsche Bank" OR "BNY Mellon" OR "JP Morgan" OR BlackRock OR Amazon)

The expected output must be:

["Asset Data Management","Data Scientist","Data Science & Analysis","Financial Modelling","Credit Structuring","Goldman Sachs","BNY Mellon","JP Morgan","BlackRock","Amazon"]

Comment: this is the result what i got
[
  'asset data management',
  'data scientist',
  'data science & analysis',
  'financial modelling',
  'credit structuring',
  'goldman sachs',
  'deutsche bank',
  'bny mellon',
  'jp morgan',
  'data',
  'science',
  '&',
  'blackrock',
  'amazon'
]

Comment: In your expected output i can see all the data. Then what is the difference between `AND` and `OR` ?

Comment: i just want all the variables and words expect OR AND and all the operator

Comment: Got it! I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using regex to perform string [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) operation.

`/AND|OR/g` -  This regex is used to split the original string with `AND` and `OR` and will return the array.

`/"|\(|\)/ig` - This regex is used to replace all the `(`, `)` & `"` with the empty string.

Working Demo **:**

```js
const str = '("Asset Data Management") AND "Data Scientist" AND ("Data Science & Analysis" OR "Financial Modelling" OR "Credit Structuring") AND ("Goldman Sachs" OR "Deutsche Bank" OR "BNY Mellon" OR "JP Morgan" OR BlackRock OR Amazon)';

const strArr = str.split(/AND|OR/g);

const finalArr = strArr.map(elem => {
    return elem.trim().replaceAll(/"|\(|\)/g, '')
});

console.log(finalArr);
```